# jQuery and generating links

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get jQuery to generate the link for a get such that I don't have to try to hand code all the query parameters?

Alternative to doing this:

```
$('a.csvBtn').attr('href',"CSVReporter?cam=" + id + "&range);
```

As we know `jquery.get({url:n, data:xxx});` and jQuery takes the data and builds a link to the url http://blah.com/n?x=1&x=2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`jQuery.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to convert an object into a query string.

```
var qs = {};
qs.cam = id; 
qs.range = 'blah';
var query_string  = jQuery.param(qs); //for id=foo, this will be cam=foo&range=blah
```

Or, [in use](http://jsfiddle.net/A88ec/):

```
$('a.csvBtn').attr('href', function(){
     var qs = {cam : id, range : 'blah'};
     return "CSVReporter?"+jQuery.param(qs); 
});
```